# Running String Command to Install Python from Java (Windows)

Tags: java, python, windows, logfile

Consider the following String command:

```
C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\Python-3.6.9\python.exe -m pip install -r C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\packages\requirements.txt  --find-links --no-index > C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\logs\python.log 2>&1
```

This command install python and its packages based on the requirements file `requirements.txt`, and then put the output of the command (both stdout and stderr) in a file called `python.log`.

When I run this command on Windows from the command line, it works perfectly, and I have my python.log file created with all the logs. However, when I run it from java, the command doesn't create the python.log file.

Two ways I have tried so far:

***1. Using Runtime exec:***

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script_WINDOWS);
```

With script_windows equals to: `pythonInterpreter+" -m pip install -r "+requirementsFilePath+" --find-links "+pathToPackages+" --no-index > "+ pythonLogFileLocation +File.separator+"python.log 2>&1"`
Which is exactly the same command I put above.

With this method, Runtime does install python for me but I have no python.log file created.

***2. Using ProcessBuilder:***

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(script_WINDOWS);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(FileUtils.getFile(pythonLogFileLocation+"python.log"), line, "UTF-8");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(FileUtils.getFile(pythonLogFileLocation+"python.log"), "\n", "UTF-8");

    }
```

This method ends in the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\Python-3.6.9\python.exe -m pip install -r C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\packages\requirements.txt --find-links C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\packages --no-index > C:\TS\Veit\Test\python\logs\python.log 2>&1": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Since the command works perfectly from the command line, I think it's the way I'm trying to execute it from Java that is causing the problem of the python.log file not being created. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that exec needs to spawn an instance of cmd.exe in order to use output redirection. See https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-java

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! Could you please put your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that exec needs to spawn an instance of cmd.exe in order to use output redirection. See stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-java